I can't set a page as unpublished
I already have page in drupal have status published and when I change status to draft still page not change status to draft it's seen published


How can I solve this problem?

“Draft” means “new draft”, and creating a new draft doesn’t unpublish an existing revision. If the content was published before you created the draft, it will stay published after. Either you’re missing the appropriate workflow step to un-publish, often called “Archive”, or maybe you don’t have permission to use it

I am admin of website and I don't see any archive option so you can guide me how can reach to it

Best I can do is point you to the documentation

and I need this option because my case is I need to unpublish content and when normal user reach to this page give him access denied

As Clive mention, you need to go through the documentation for workflow if it is used on your site. Using workflow, you can hide publishing option for specific roles. check what role you are logged in as and validate workflow for that role and permissions for specific content type that you like to have Publishing option.
Hope this helps. In future, please include additional information like Role, Drupal Version, any specific module if you are referring to get answers quicker.
try check your config settings for user.role specific yml file make sure the user role has workflow.workflow.editorial settings enable if you are using workflow. you can also allow administer node permissions but that is only for the trusted roles as this will allow users to delete revisions.
